# can I not change partition when I use window with spark/scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `RDD` , the `RDD'partition` of result changes to 1 when I use `window`,can I not change `partition` when I use `window`?
this is my code:

```
 val rdd=sc.parallelize(List(1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8),4)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(m_sparkCtx)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val result = rdd.toDF("values").withColumn("csum", sum(col("values")).over(Window.orderBy("values"))).rdd
    println(result.getNumPartitions+"rdd2")
```

My input'partition is 4,I want my result'partition is alse 4,is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: by `the RDD of result changes to 1` you mean the number of partitions changes to 1?

Comment: yes,Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DataFrame withColumn and not to change partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382123/how-to-use-dataframe-withcolumn-and-not-to-change-partition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partitions of the RDD is 1 as expected this is because your are performing a Window function on a DataFrame without a partitionBy clause. So all the data has to be grouped into a single partition in this case.

When we include a partitionBy clause in our Window function then the number of partitions in the result RDD is no longer 1 as shown below. In the below example we have included an-another column in called `col1` in the original dataframe and the same window function is applied with a `partitionBy` clause on `col1` column.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

scala> val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List((1,1),(3,1),(2,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,3),(7,3),(8,3)),4)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[49] at parallelize at <console>:28

scala> val result = rdd.toDF("values", "col1").withColumn("csum", sum(col("values")).over(Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("values"))).rdd
result: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[58] at rdd at <console>:30

scala> result.getNumPartitions
res6: Int = 200
```

Comment: why the result' partition is 200 ,my input'partition is 4,I want my result'partition is alse 4,is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: 200 is the default number of partitions in Spark SQL.