# how can I keep partition'number not change when I use window.partitionBy() function with spark/scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `RDD` , the `RDD' partition` of result changes to 200 when I use `window`,can I not change `partition` when I use `window`?

This is my code:

```
val rdd= sc.parallelize(List(1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8),4)
val result = rdd.toDF("values").withColumn("csum", sum(col("values")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("values")))).rdd
println(result.getNumPartitions + "rdd2")
```

My input partition is 4, why result partition is 200?

I want my result partition to be also 4.

Is there any cleaner solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note: As mentioned by @eliasah - it's not possible to avoid
>   repartition when using window functions with spark

---

> - Why result partition is 200?

[Spark doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options)
The default value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` which 
Configures the number of partitions to use when shuffling data for joins or aggregations - is 200

> - How can I repartition to 4?

You can use:

```
coalesce(4)
```

or

```
repartition(4)
```

[spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html)

**coalesce(numPartitions)**     Decrease the number of partitions in the RDD to numPartitions. Useful for running operations more efficiently after filtering down a large dataset.

**repartition(numPartitions)** Reshuffle the data in the RDD randomly to create either more or fewer partitions and balance it across them. This always shuffles all data over the network.

Comment: The OP wants to avoid repartition. You can point out that it's not possible when using window functions with spark.

Comment: if I use repartition ,The order of the data will change，then I have to use sortBy() to sort the data，is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: There is no cleaner solution. You'll need to use orderBy/sortBy and that's why I didn't mention it in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44384638/3415409

Answer (score 2):

(also added this answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44384638/3415409)

I was just reading about controlling the number of partitions when using groupBy aggregation, from https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-performance-tuning-groupBy-aggregation.html, it seems the same trick works with Window, in my code I'm defining a window like

```
windowSpec = Window \
    .partitionBy('colA', 'colB') \
    .orderBy('timeCol') \
    .rowsBetween(1, 1)
```

and then doing

```
next_event = F.lead('timeCol', 1).over(windowSpec)
```

and creating a dataframe via

```
df2 = df.withColumn('next_event', next_event)
```

and indeed, it has 200 partitions. But, if I do

```
df2 = df.repartition(10, 'colA', 'colB').withColumn('next_event', next_event)
```

it has 10!